# DeepCloner not actually copying the properties?

Tags: c#, .net, deep-copy

So I've been trying to play around little bit with a NuGet package called [DeepCloner](https://github.com/force-net/DeepCloner#performance).

I have a simple class called *IdInfo* with one property and constructor

```cs
public class IdInfo
{
    public int IdNumber;
    public IdInfo(int idNumber)
    {
        IdNumber = idNumber;
    }
}
```

Then, I have a class called *Person*, with couple of properties and constructors

```cs
public class Person
{
    public int Age;
    public DateTime BirthDate;
    public string Name;
    public IdInfo IdInfo;

    public Person(int age, DateTime birthDate, string name, IdInfo idInfo)
    {
        Age = age;
        BirthDate = birthDate;
        Name = name;
        IdInfo = idInfo;
    }
    public Person()
    { }
}
```

In my main class, I would like to achieve Deep cloning by using DeepCloner as mentioned above. This is what I have tried

```cs
internal class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //create a dummy Person to get cloned
        Person p1 = new Person();
        p1.Age = 42;
        p1.BirthDate = Convert.ToDateTime("1977-01-05");
        p1.Name = "Aleksandar Petrovic";
        p1.IdInfo = new IdInfo(123);

        //create a dummy Person to append those values to
        Person clonedPerson = new Person();

        //call a method for DeepCloning (down in the code)
        PerformDeepCloning(p1, clonedPerson);
        //after finishing with the method, "clonedPerson" value stay null, why?
        

        Console.WriteLine("Displaying values of both persons (1. p1, 2. Cloned person)\n");
        DisplayValues(p1);

        //System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'
        DisplayValues(clonedPerson);
    }

    public static void DisplayValues(Person p)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("    Name: {0:s}, Age: {1:d}, BirthDate: {2:MM/dd/yy}", p.Name, p.Age, p.BirthDate);
        Console.WriteLine("    ID#: {0:d}\n", p.IdInfo.IdNumber);
    }

    //method gets 2 elements, first has values that should be copied to the second
    public static void PerformDeepCloning(Person source, Person destination)
    {
        //call a method from the package
        destination = source.DeepClone();
        //this works fine
        Console.WriteLine("DEEP CLONED NAME = " + destination.Name);
    }
}
```

I understand why the values are shown in the SC down below

[image]

But why are the values not applied to the variable "clonedPerson" afterwards?
[image]

Comment: You need to declare `PerformDeepCloning()` like so: `public static void PerformDeepCloning(Person source, ref Person destination)`. Otherwise you are not changing the `Person` reference passed to `PerformDeepCloning()` - you are just changing a COPY of the reference that's passed to it.

Comment: That's correct, thank you very much. OMW to learn more about "ref" keyword.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your code is currently written, you are assigning a complete new object to your `destination` parameter. But this does not change the object you passed into that parameter. To overcome this issue there are several possibilites (in order of my personal preference)

1. You can just define `PerformDeepCloning` to return a `Person`

   ```
    public static Person PerformDeepCloning(Person source)
    {
      //call a method from the package
      Person destination = source.DeepClone();
      //this works fine
      Console.WriteLine("DEEP CLONED NAME = " + destination.Name);
      return destination;
    }
   ```

   and call it like this

   ```
    Person otherPerson = PerformDeepCloning(person);
   ```

   This would seem the most natural way for me to do it, instead of populating `out` or `ref` parameters of a method returning `void`, why not just return the result via `return` keyword?
2. Use the [`out` keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/out-parameter-modifier) which was specifically designed for such situations (ie creating a new object inside the called method and pass it to the caller if `return` isn't possible for whatever resons)

   ```
    public static void PerformDeepCloning(Person source, out Person destination)
    {
      //call a method from the package
      destination = source.DeepClone();
      //this works fine
      Console.WriteLine("DEEP CLONED NAME = " + destination.Name);
    }
   ```

   and then call it like this

   ```
    //you must not assign a value here, when using the out keyword        
    Person otherPerson;
    PerformDeepCloning(person, out otherPerson);
   ```

   or starting with C#7 you can also use an [inline declaration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/out-parameter-modifier#calling-a-method-with-an-out-argument)

   ```
    //no need to delare Person otherPerson; prior to the call
    PerformDeepCloning(person, out Person otherPerson);
   ```
3. Use the [`ref` keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/ref) which is capable of updating the reference which was passed in.

   ```
    public static void PerformDeepCloning(Person source, ref Person destination)
    {
      //call a method from the package
      destination = source.DeepClone();
      //this works fine
      Console.WriteLine("DEEP CLONED NAME = " + destination.Name);
    }
   ```

   and then call it like this

   ```
    Person otherPerson = new Person(); 
    PerformDeepCloning(person, ref otherPerson);
   ```

   But as you are creating a new instance of a `Person` anyways, you don't need to create a new object before the call (because this will be thrown away immediately) but initialize the `otherPerson` with `null`. But then you of course have to sure, you don't access `otherPerson`'s properties, before you created an instance.

   ```
    Person otherPerson = null; 
    PerformDeepCloning(person, ref otherPerson);
   ```

Comment: In the first scenario, am I supposed to return a "**Person**" which is a class, or "**destination**" which is a variable?

Comment: @aca Of course it should be `destination` ... my fault ...